# How to resolve a RoboBrowser Import Error in Python?

Tags: python, import, installation, robobrowser

I am a beginner trying to learn web scraping with python. I tried to import RoboBrowser module in Python 3.7.
When I install it using `pip install robobrowser` in the terminal, I get a list of 'Requirement already satisfied'. So I am assuming its installed properly.

However when I run `from robobrowser import RoboBrowser` in Python, its gives an import error as shown below.

`ImportError: cannot import name 'cached_property' from 'werkzeug' (/Users/ashreetsangotra/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py)`

Here is the screenshot of the complete error for reference:

[Click here for the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Rbah.png) Sorry Stack Overflow won't let me embed the screenshot directly as for now.

Please advice on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Ashreet Sangotra

Make sure your `Werkzeug==0.16.1` version,
it will solve your error.

Thanks